# Android Studio Bumblebee emulator sdk gphone x86(mobile) doesn't show

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

So updating to Android Studio Bumblebee appeared to bring a new emulator preloaded, `sdk gphone x86(mobile)`. If I run on this emulator, my app appears to compile, but I can't actually find the location of the emulator on my screen.

There are other problems, like Logcat not showing, but I imagine that's a separate issue.

[image: default emulator doesn't hidden]

Answer (score 0):

Go to View>Tool Windows>Device Manager

[image: Go to View>Tool Windows>Device Manager]

Then you will see all your emulators

[image: Then you will see all your emulators]